# Two monitors work as if they were a single one

Tags: linux, xorg, xinerama

I have 3 monitors (1 on an Intel card, 2 on Nvidia).
After some magic with `xorg.conf` they started to work, but the two Nvidia monitors work as if they were a single, wide monitor (any maximized window will cover both displays and end up split in the middle).

```
    Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "X.org Configured"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
        Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen0"
        Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen2"
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
        Option         "Xinerama"      "on"
    EndSection

    Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor1"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor2"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"

    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen1"
        Device     "Card1"
        Monitor    "Monitor1"
        Option     "TwinView" "0"
    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen2"
        Device     "Card1"
        Monitor    "Monitor2"
        Option     "TwinView" "0"
    EndSection
```

How can I configure my windowing system so that it properly recognizes monitor boundaries?

Comment: Hi Alex, and welcome! It's not clear what your question is: what would you like to do that the current config doesn't do?

Comment: @dhag Hi! I have some problems with language, so i try. I have 3 monitors 1280x1024 for example. Monitor0 works great, but Monitor1 and Monitor2 have one screen with 2560x1024 (one wide screen). But i need individual screen with 1280x1024 for every monitor.

Comment: OK, that's perfectly clear now. I submitted an edit to integrate this into your question.

Comment: I can't remember the precise details so I'm not submitting as an Answer. To fix this you need to remove the xinerama settings. Install `nvidia-settings` and let it discover your two screens. Configure the screens graphically how you would like them to be. Hit save. If necessary update the `xorg.conf` as it dictates (but I don't recall it doing that). Be happy.

Comment: A quick solution (don't have time to write proper answer) is to use: https://github.com/phillipberndt/fakexrandr , it allows arbitrary slicing of the available screens.